# How to remove last character from string?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I remove `;` semicolon from the end of string in sql ? 
For example I have a string and it has values like `'TES; ASD;'` AND `'SDF;'`

I want values like `'TES; ASD'` AND `'SDF'`. Need to trim `;` from the end of string only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`trim()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions235.htm):

```
select trim(trailing ';' from string)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the last character in the string, use SUBSTR:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(STRING, 1, LENGTH(STRING)-1) ...
```

Or you can use the RTRIM function to trim off a semicolon on the right end of the string:

```
SELECT RTRIM(STRING, ';') ...
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=60b67a681be6e4ee9c856a148d719b22)

Answer (score 0):

Using `RTRIM`:

```
with data as(
select 'TES; ASD;' str from dual union all
select 'SDF;' from dual
)
select str, RTRIM(str, ';') new_str from data;

STR       NEW_STR  
--------- ---------
TES; ASD; TES; ASD 
SDF;      SDF
```